# toString() on JS associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative

Is it possible to call '.toString()' on an associative array in Javascript.

```
var theString = jsonData['item'].toLowerCase();
var theString = jsonData.item.toLowerCase();
```

Neither of these work for me in converting the array item's value to lower case.

In PHP I can do this by:

```
strtolower($array['item']);
```

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:
Here is my exact code:

```
var correctAnswer = jsonData[setname][qname]['answers'][answerval];
if(lockcase == false){
orrectAnswer = correctAnswer.toString().toLowerCase();  
}
```

And here is the message from the Chrome debug menu:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Concatenate the returned value with an empty string literal:

```
var theString = ("" + jsonData['item']).toLowerCase();
var theString = ("" + jsonData.item   ).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to be working.
I think you can't do that because it is interpreted as the function is interpreted as a child object of the array.

Comment: @HelloInvader So you mean a boolean value is returned?

Comment: Thanks! I prefer this method because when working with IE7 the other method requires a library.

Comment: For implicit type conversions like this, I always prefer `''+val` over `val+''` because of evaluation order; consider `1+1+''` vs `''+1+1`, the first is `"2"` and the second `"11"` (which I find more intuitive).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
JSON.stringify(jsonData['item'])
```

This will return you a `String`, so `toString()` is not needed.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to be working. I've added my exact code to the question and the error in the chrome debug bar.

Comment: You don't need toString. JSON.stringify returns a String (hence 'stringify').